# How to show multiple unrelated 1:N records in Crystal

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a data set that I am reporting on. However, some of the data is duplicated and some is not:

```
ID   Project   Org   Type   Facility   AssessorManager   Assessor 
123   Proj1    Org1  Ty1    Facil1     Smith              Jones    
123   Proj1    Org2  Ty1    Facil2     Smith              Black 
123   Proj1    Org2  Ty1    Facil3     Smith              Black 
234   Proj1    Org3  Ty2    Facil3     Harris             Jones 
234   Proj1    Org1  Ty2    Facil3     Harris             Jones 
393   Proj2    Org2  Ty3    Facil1     Smith              Black
```

So, for an ID, there is a 1:1 relationship with the Project, Type, and AssessorManager; and a 1:N relationship with the Org, Facility, and Assessor.

I want a report that doesn't repeat more than necessary, and have reported the 1:1 data, and then stored procedures for each of the 1:N data sets. I get a result like below, but it is dog SLOW.

```
ID   Project   Org   Type   Facility   AssessorManager   Assessor 
123  Proj1     Org1  Ty1    Facil1     Smith             Jones 
               Org2         Facil2                       Black 
                            Facil3 

234  Proj1     Org3  Ty2    Facil3     Harris            Jones 
               Org1 

393  Proj2     Org2  Ty3    Facil1     Smith             Black
```

Can I make a function for the 1:N fields that orders the data and shows distinct data?  I can use the suppress if duplicated option for the field, but I need to sort each field within the ID on its own.  I can't use group by and set groups, because there are 4 1:N fields, and they are all independent of each other.

(Doing the group by in the past has resulted in a report that looks like the following:

```
ID   Project   Org   Type   Facility   AssessorManager   Assessor 
123  Proj1     Org1  Ty1    Facil1     Smith             Jones 
                                                         Black 
                            Facil2                       Jones
                                                         Black
                            Facil3                       Jones
                                                         Black
               Org2         Facil1                       Jones 
                                                         Black 
                            Facil2                       Jones
                                                         Black
                            Facil3                       Jones
                                                         Black
```

...etc.)

EDIT...
answer...
I accepted PowerUser's answer, mostly using his second suggestion.  I added fields to my query.  It still had duplication, because some of the 1:N fields were query and sort fields.  There is probably more duplication than shown here, but this is the idea.  Also, rather than using commas to separate the values in the memo fields, I used a return character.

```
ID   Project   Org   Orgs       Type    Facility   Facilities         AssessorManager   Assessors 
123  Proj1     Org1  Org1,Org2  Ty1     Facil1   Facil1,Facil2,Facil3   Smith          Jones,Black 
123  Proj1     Org2  Org1,Org2  Ty1     Facil2   Facil1,Facil2,Facil3   Smith          Jones,Black 
123  Proj1     Org2  Org1,Org2  Ty1     Facil3   Facil1,Facil2,Facil3   Smith          Jones,Black
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 for your examples! So let me get this straight.  It works, but you want it to work faster?

1. In your 3rd example table, I think you're using a Helper (aka Index) table and right joining to your data.  That would explain why you have a row for `Proj 1, Org 1, Black` when there is no record in your original data set. Inner joining would fix that, but make sure it doesn't produce any other problems in the process.
2. Instead of grouping by ID, then Proj, the Org, etc., you can make a single concatenated field for grouping, i.e. `GroupBy=[ID]&[Proj]&[Org]`. That will speed things up a bit since you only have 1 grouping level.
3. Based on your tags, i believe your datasource is SQL Server 2008.  If you are pulling from a query, try making a temporary static table instead.  That will simplify things considerably for Crystal.

(If one of these suggestions is helpful, please tell me which one.)

Comment: I went with a combination of 2 and 3.  I actually added memo fields to my query, and put in the combined sets of data in each.  There is a lot of duplication, but it only happens the one time, and eliminates the need for subreports.  I don't think I can show a picture in a comment, however.